# How do i plot markers with lambert coordinates on map instead of lat/long in react-leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I do have some lambert coordinates like
[149031,114032]
[164787,156787]
Do I need to change these lat/long values to assign position attribute
or can i plot with the above coordinates

Is there any conversion avlble from lambert coordinates to lat/long values

I tried with L.point(149031,114032) but not didn't progress anything

Comment: One option is to first transorm your coordinates to EPSG:4326 (from EPSG:31300 I assume).  See https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/

Comment: proj4 is good library to use for projections 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/proj4